# Rails Server Issue (Spring)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

```
/Users/woodbineone/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/Users/woodbineone/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/Users/woodbineone/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `block in load'
/Users/woodbineone/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/woodbineone/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/Users/woodbineone/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<main>'
/Users/woodbineone/.rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/woodbineone/.rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/woodbineone/workspace/blog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It's not clear there is a question here. What command did you run to generate this stack trace? Would you mind fixing the format?

Comment: Yes. Kindly add more details and how you reached to this problem.

Comment: I generated this output when I ran: rails -s

Comment: I understand there may be methods to correct this problem involving modifications to the generated files. I am not interested in those. When rails generates everything, it should be good to go.